# url_for method inside template is not working

Tags: python, html, flask

thank you so much for your help.

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="{{ url_for('details') }}" method="POST">
    {{ form.firstName.label }} {{form.firstName}}
    <br>
    {{form.submit}}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

when click on submit button i get `Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL`. looks like the action attribute in the above code is not redirecting to details function which will take to details view page when submit button is clicked but when i manually type details in the address bar it redirects to details view page with no results. wondering why it button click is not working

details.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {{session['firstName']}}
{% endblock %}
```

p.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, EmailField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, EqualTo

app = Flask( __name__ )
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "for test"
class userInfo(FlaskForm):
    firstName = StringField("enter first name:", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    form = userInfo()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['firstName'] = form.firstName.data
        form.firstName.data = ''
        return redirect(url_for("details"))
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
@app.route("/details")
def details():
    return render_template("details.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

i want to navigate to details view page when my form in index view page is submitted but when button is clicked i get error message instead of navigating to different view page.

Comment: The `/details` route does not have a `methods=` argument, therefore it defaults to only accepting GET requests, but you are sending a POST request.

Comment: And the `/details` route does not do any form processing anyway.  Why are you using that url as the form action?

Comment: i wanted to pass user input from index page to details page when form submitted using session so that i can see what has been entered in previous page when navigating to next page

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> By default, a route only responds to a `GET request`. You can use
> the method's argument of the `route()` decorator to handle different `HTTP`
> methods.

(https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods)

You should add a decorator argument *`methods=["POST"]`* to receive a `POST request`.